# Group all rows that meet a certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
  company_location count
  <chr>            <int>
1 DE                  28
2 JP                   6
3 GB                  47
4 HN                   1
5 US                 355
6 HU                   1
```

I want to get to `df2`:

```
  company_location count
  <chr>            <int>
1 DE                  28
2 GB                  47
3 US                 355
4 OTHER                8
```

`df2` is the same as `df1` but sums together all the columns with `count<10` and aggregates them in a row called `OTHER`

Does something like this exist: A group_by() function that only groups all the rows that match a particular condition into one group and leaves all the other rows in groups only containing them alone?

Comment: Add a new column that meets your grouping criteria with a `mutate` and `case_when` and use that as the grouping variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `fct_lump_min` is for - it's a function from `forcats`, which is part of the tidyverse.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(company_location = fct_lump_min(company_location, 10, count)) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(count))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   company_location count
#>   <fct>            <int>
#> 1 DE                  28
#> 2 GB                  47
#> 3 US                 355
#> 4 Other                8
```

Comment: You might want to add which package `fct_lump_min` comes from. I'm guessing `forcats`?

Comment: Yes, it's forcats, within the tidyverse @thelatemail

Answer (score 3):

Make a temporary variable regrouping `company_location` based on `count`, then `summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(company_location = replace(company_location, count < 10, 'OTHER')) %>% 
    summarise(count = sum(count))

#  company_location count
#  <chr>            <int>
#1 DE                  28
#2 GB                  47
#3 OTHER                8
#4 US                 355
```